# This intent is giving me error "The constructor Intent(Character, Class) is undefined""

Tags: android, android-intent, undefined

I am getting error at the Intent "The constructor Intent(Character, Class) is undefined Please tell me a solution!!!"

```
public class Characters extends ListFragment {
String classes[] = {"Desmond", "Altair", "Ezio", "Connor", "Haytham", "Edward", "Aveline", "Lucy", "William", "Shaun", "Rebecca", "Clay", "Vidic",
"Tabs"};
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
            String Character = classes[position];
            try{
            Class ourClass = Class.forName("com.frost.assassinswikia." + Character);
            Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Characters.this, ourClass);
            startActivity(ourIntent);
            }catch (ClassNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

}

```
@Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: I came here after playing too much assassin's creed.

Answer (score 3):

You need a Activity instance to create the intent

Fragment can access the Activity instance with [**`getActivity()`**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html)

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ourClass);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Characters.this, ourClass);
```

to

```
Intent ourIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), ourClass);
```

The [Intent constructor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E%29) you are trying to use takes a `Context` as the first parameter and your `Characters` class is not a `Context`, whereas the `Activity` that hosts it is.

This activity is available to any fragment via `getActivity()`

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
String Character = classes[position];
```

`Character` is a reserved word for the type [Character](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Character.html). You'll have to rename that variable.